# How does the "chance to hit" (or accuracy) work in Path of Exile?

Tags: path-of-exile

So there's this percentage that shows how accurate your character is when hitting.

Say I use a bow, and when you reach 100% chance to hit (or accuracy) then I believe it hits all the arrows. But after I saw that it's possible to get more percentage than 100% then my thoughts are.. Is there a limit, or is it pointless?

Comment: For which game? I assume you mean Path of Exile and not the original Diablo.

Comment: Well, in Diablo happened to get more than 100% as well, so that's why I added also the diablo tag. It's for both of them.

Comment: May I suggest you create 2 separate question for both game as someone who has only played one of the game won't really be able to fully answer the question, especially if the mechanics at work are different.

Comment: Ok, I'll leave this one aside so someone could get a summary answer of both questions. ;)

Comment: Don't do that. There's no reason to have a question like that on this site. Just edit this question to only be about one of the games, and then ask another question about the other if necessary.

Comment: Since you asked another question about Diablo, I'm going to edit Diablo out of this one to make sure that it is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [Path of Exile Official Wiki](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Accuracy), the formula for actual hit chance is:

```
Attacker's Accuracy / ( Attacker's Accuracy + ((Defender's Evasion / 4) ^ 0.8) )
```

This means that accuracy is used to counteract an opponent's evasion, and vice-versa, with more evasion points needed the higher evasion gets, and also with more accuracy rating needed the higher your chance to hit. There are, however, a number of caveats:

- The actual chance to hit is normally capped to between 5% and 95%.
- [Resolute Technique](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Resolute_Technique) allows an attacker to have 100% chance to hit, no matter what, at a cost of never scoring critical hits.
- [Unwavering Stance](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Unwavering_Stance) allows a defender to become immune to stuns, at a cost of all attackers having 100% chance to hit against them.
- There is also a [Chance to Dodge](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Dodge) statistic, which is a second check, independent of evasion/accuracy.
- The actual hitting/missing is not technically a random chance, but uses [a mechanic called 'entropy'](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Evasion#Mechanics) to even out short-term streaks of hits/misses.

A good resource is the first post in [this thread](http://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/58406) on the Path of Exile forums about accuracy/evasion, which includes a link to [a Google Doc](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ArsB7KohOhhpdFJucWQyUGdOXy03cXIyMzBVZDRWZFE#gid=2) with several charts of evasion vs. accuracy and average monster stats at various levels.

Comment: Defender sounds a bit confusing, why not `target`?

Comment: I honestly don't see any way at all in which Defender and Attacker aren't clear. Can you clarify what your problem is with it?

Comment: In many games I could generally refer easily the fighting opponent, as target. Defender sounds more like a role inside of a team, someone that must defend something else but itself, but hey it's just a PoV!